Possible to write/edit metadata in Mp3 files in Swift in 2024
My app allows the user to create recording and save them an MP3 file. Ideally, I would like to put some information into the file to make a record of who created the recording.  MP3 files apparently store metadata in an id3 tag at the beginning of the file.
It is possible to read it using:
import AVFoundation

let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/mp3/file.mp3"))
let metadata = asset.commonMetadata

for item in metadata {
   if let value = item.value {
      switch item.commonKey?.rawValue {
      case "title":
         print("Title: \(value)")
      case "artist":
         print("Artist: \(value)")
      default:
         break
      }
   }
}

All of the resources I found on the web suggest neither AVKit nor AVFoundation support adding or editing the metadata. A few links such as this one suggest you need to use a 3rd party library. One SO answer from 2018 suggests a way but it was not reliable.  I found an interesting framework here and post here but all things being equal prefer to avoid third party frameworks.
Now in 2024, is it possible to write/edit metadata in an MP3 using Swift or otherwise preserve the creator of the recording in the file.
Thanks for any suggestions.

If you found an open source framework which does the job for you, why don't you have a look at its implementation to figure out how to achieve your goals without adding the framework as a dependency if you prefer to avoid 3rd party dependencies?

The frameworks I've linked to/looked out contain a ton of files and code that could break. Not at all lightweight.

What about AVAssetWriter ? Starting from this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071731/adding-metadata-to-generated-audio-file I see that such object can be initialized with an AVFileType which has among his set the option mp3. I didn’t try personally but it might be a viable way to go
